# Failed assertion: "constraints.hasBoundedWidth" is not true

Tags: flutter

I am making a feed page for my flutter application but I can't navigate to this page, I am getting this error: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 1924 pos 16: 'constraints.hasBoundedWidth': is not true. package:flutter/…/rendering/viewport.dart:1924

[image]

Can someone please help

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: BlocBuilder<FeedPostBloc, FeedPostState>(
    builder: (context, postState) {
      switch (postState.status) {
        case PostStatus.failure:
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              'Bir hata oldu',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
            ),
          );

        case PostStatus.success:
          if (postState.posts.isEmpty) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text('Post bulunamadı'),
            );
          }
          return DraggableHome(
            appBarColor: HexColor("#562C2C"),
            title: Text(
              'Sosyal',
              style: TextStyle(color: darkColor),
            ),
            headerWidget: Container(
              color: HexColor("#562C2C"),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Sosyal",
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .displayMedium!
                      .copyWith(color: HexColor("#F3D8C7")),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            body: [
              FittedBox(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return index >= postState.posts.length
                      ? const IndicatorWidget()
                      : PostListItem(
                          post: postState.posts[index],
                        );
                },
                itemCount: postState.hasReachedMax
                    ? postState.posts.length
                    : postState.posts.length + 1,
                controller: _scrollController,
              ))
            ],
            backgroundColor: HexColor("#F3D8C7"),
          );

        default:
          return Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Yükleniyor...',
                    style: TextStyle(color: darkColor),
                  ),
                  CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: darkColor,
                    strokeWidth: 1.5,
                  )
                ]),
          );
      }
    },
  ),
  backgroundColor: HexColor("#F3D8C7"),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body: [
  ListView.builder(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return index >= postState.posts.length
          ? const IndicatorWidget()
          : PostListItem(
              post: postState.posts[index],
            );
    },
    itemCount: postState.hasReachedMax
        ? postState.posts.length
        : postState.posts.length + 1,
    controller: _scrollController,
  ),
],
```